# Write into XML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Hi i got a existing XML file and want to add a new entry via Javascript (atm without any form or stuff like that just hard coded), so my question is how to handel this to add a new book.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I wish JavaScript could write a new entry in your "Accepted Answers" record. Oh wait, it can if you click that little green checkmark! ;)

Comment: Where are you running this JavaScript? Usually JavaScript running in a browser has no way to write to a local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XML.BeginNode(“Foo”);
XML.Attrib(“Bar”, “Some Value”);
XML.EndNode();
//Produces: <Foo Bar=”Some Value” />
```

Check below URL also.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12504/Writing-XML-using-JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid JavaScript cannot write to local files as you would wish. You can produce XML, but not write/save it to file...